# What is the best, cross platfrom, way to parse a text file?

Tags: c++, c, string, file, stream

I would like to port my Windows code to native C++ and need to get rid of all CLI code. I found .NET very helpful in parsing textual input but when I started re-writing it in C++ I was still wont to code in C with `fseek` and `char *` in place of `String`. Finding C++ has a `string` type in the `std` namespace I opened up my STL documentation (from a zip archive) and found ["string_discussion.html"](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string_discussion.html) which began, "Strings in SGI STL" and continued to describe an oversight potentially causing intermittent errors.

Is `std::string` safe? What is the relationship of `std` to STL if any? Is C file IO *that* dangerous and C++ stream and string IO so much better?

Comment: If you want to code in C++, why is the question also tagged with C?

Comment: the best cross platform way would be using Qt framework.

Comment: Perhaps best to start by revising a few C++ basics (the FAQ has a great list of books). The SGI STL is from 1994 and entirely irrelevant in modern C++, for instance, so you'd be better off if you knew the basics of the standard library.

Comment: arne Tagged with C because that is an option at my disposal, one that I am familiar with and tending towards, @cyber_rag, thanks but I'd rather learn a more/the standard way first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues described in the document exist for some compilers, notably MSVC, but I've never run into an actual problem in the real world. The GNU compilers implement the described "unshareable" strings, that is, using non-const `operator[]` makes the string unshareable and creates a copy if required.

The STL classes are, by definition, not threadsafe and need to be surrounded by locks if accessed from multiple threads; I think that this is a feature as it makes them significantly faster and allows for the implementation of lock-free algorithms.

The relation between `std` and the STL is basically that the STL has been integrated into the C++ standard library which lives in the `std` namespace. The standard has evolved since, but remains largely compatible.

In general it is safe for use in text parsers: a typical pattern for line-by-line parsing is

```
std::istream &is;
for(std::string line; getline(is, line);)
{
    // parse line
}
```

Comment: Simon I like the pattern. The example in that SGI STL link recreated the error without threads which got me worried. Day to day I don't use much mulit-threading but that might not be true in a few years.